# Is there any way to use my Verizon hot spot as the internet source for a router?

Tags: router

I recently bought a slingbox which requires a router in order to connect it. I'm in a contract with Verizon until April 2013 otherwise I would just get a different internet provider that would provide me with a router. Any ideas? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mac share your wireless connection with your ethernet connection and connect you slingbox to the ethernet port:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cradlepoint routers can do this. 
http://www.cradlepoint.com/news-and-events/news/cradlepoint-announces-support-novatel-mifi-latest-firmware-release